# Foolproof way to scrape articles

Tags: scraping

I'm looking for a very, very simple way to scrape all articles released on several websites based on these criteria:

- I can't code, so it really has to be very straightforward (i.e. no Python or so) and perhaps even with a tutorial or something. I've tried Octoparse, but for the hell of me I couldn't get it to work as needed. Would something like Portia work? Would you recommend it?
- It'd be a one-off project and would involve up to 10,000 articles in all, so I don't want any commitments and/or (long) subscriptions.
- The headline + body text would be enough, optionally also the date of publication.
- Ideally, one big (plain text) file for each website so that I can feed the texts easily into a language corpus tool.

For each solution, please explain whether there are any associated risks, such as for my Gmail account, for deploying a web scraper and thus 'acting like a web robot'.

Thank you!

Edited (to add information requested by Izzy):

- Yes, I'm looking for a ready-to-use software
- I use Windows 10
- I'd be willing to pay, say, up to 50$/€ in a one-time fee. Since this would be more of a pastime, rather than a monetizable thing, I can't pay more than that.